# The Network Profile is extremely limited in functionality and needs a revamp

Tags: discussion, profile-page, network-profile

It appears that [the activity tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/445/thomas-owens?tab=activity) can only generate 5 pages of activity. For me, this means that my network activity when filtered to show posts ends in early September 2020 and, as I write more answers more of my history will be unavailable on this page.

This hampers the ability for me to use my network profile page. For example, I link to it on my site with the intention of letting people see my contributions to the Stack Exchange network. However, it's not very useful if that history is only a few months of contributions.

This isn't the only issue with the network profile. In the past, [I've pointed out that links are broken, meaning that an About Me that links to other sources doesn't function](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306021/572).

The more I try to use Network Profiles, the more issues I run into. It seems like some effort should be put into discovery and thinking about how to make Network Profiles work for everyone and not give false surface-level impressions about what can be done through the profile.

Comment: There is some SEDE queries, each showing a bit of activity, here's one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300953/282094, not sure that expansion is planned: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304231/282094 - distantly (?) similar duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94605/282094

Comment: @Rob Those don't help me at all. You shouldn't need an SEDE query to allow someone to view your history across the network. I don't think Random Internet People would find that useful.

Comment: @Rob It seems like there's been no activity on these issues for 4+ years. Close to 7 in some cases.